# Rails: Cache or not Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, caching

I'm trying to use cache but I want to know if is possibile to cache data that change frequently.

If data change often is caching a good strategy?

If I cache a posts list with fragment cache, and a user edit his post, cache is upload automatically? How does cache work with personalized data? (for example page with current_user.data eccc)

In this case is cache upload automatically when @posts is updated?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% cache post do %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/post_list', locals: {post: post} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:** The cache will update when the cache key is invalid.  In your case, when a particular post's `updated_at` field is later than what is in the cache, the cache will be updated.  It is important to note that the cache update happens when the new data in the view is rendered for the first time and not when the data is updated in the database.

**Long Answer:** I strongly recommend you read [Caching with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) for the fundamentals.

The code block posted in the question uses [Rails' Fragment Caching](https://blog.ragnarson.com/2016/11/02/introduction-to-fragment-caching-in-rails.html).  The `cache product` call will generate a cache key that is a combination of `post.id`, `post.updated_at` and an MD5 hash of the view template.  Rails will search the cache for that key, and if found, will return the cache value without having to render the partial.  This is a cache hit.  If the cache key is not found, then Rails will render the partial and store the results in the cache for future use.  This is a cache miss.

The tricky part of any caching scheme is cache validation, this is, ensuring the data served by the cache is valid and accurate.  If the data in the database has changed for example, we want to serve the database data as opposed to the stale (old) cache data.

Rails solves this problem "automagically" by building the cache key described above.  If the data in the `post` record changes, then `post.updated_at` will be updated and a new cache key will be used which will lead to a cache miss.  This is what you want to happen when the data in the cache is old.  Likewise, if the view template changes, then the MD5 hash of the view will change and the cache key will also be updated leading to a cache miss.

Where this could become a problem, is if the `shared/post_list` partial references data or variables that are not captured in the `post` record.  For example, if the partial changes depending on whether or not a user is an administrator, then you will want to capture the user's administrator status in the cache key.  You would do something like this:

```
<% cache [post, current_user.admin?] do %>
```

Another common example is if the partial references other database objects that are related to post.  Let's say for the sake of argument that your partial renders a list of `post.comments`.  If a comment changes, but that change does not touch the `updated_at` field of the `post` record, then the data served by the cache will be invalid.  This problem is solved by adding `touch: true` to the `belongs_to` association:

```
Class Comment < ActiveRecord:base
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
  ...
end
```

The above code will update the `post` record's `updated_at` any time one of its comments changes.

Finally, Rails offers something called [Collection Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#collection-caching) which is a more efficient way of rendering a collection of partials/templates.  You could implement this form of caching in your example by replacing the entire `each` loop with one line of code:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/post_list', collection: @posts, cached: true %>
```

There is a lot more to caching than is described here.  I recommend you read the guides linked in this post so you have a thorough understanding of cache validation.  You can speed your server up significantly with caching.  I have seen server response times drop by an order of magnitude in some cases.  However, unless you are careful, you could end up serving stale date in your cache.